# The function log(x) in C is always giving the same value

Tags: c, logarithm

Basically, I am trying to find the logarithm of a number using the log(x) function in the math.h library of C. But, for any and every value that I enter for the variable x, I end up with the same answer: -722.259365. Where is the problem with my code below?

I am kind of new to C, so please don't mind if this is too silly a mistake.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
void PrintLogarithm(double x){
    if(x<=0){
        printf("Positive numbers only please.\n");
        return;
    }
    double Result = log(x);
    printf("%f\n", Result);
}
int main(){
    double x;
    scanf("%f", &x);
    PrintLogarithm(x);
    return 0;
}
```

I am kind of new to C, so please don't mind if this is too silly a mistake.

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: Also, print the return value of `scanf` to make sure you're parsing the number correctly

Comment: 1? 2? -5? 10? Same answer for every input.

Comment: If you entered a negative number and the if statement didn't trigger, then scanf isn't doing what you think it is. I suspect you need \n in the format

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%lf` for `double`?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to paste it here, but the code doesn't have stdio.h included.

Comment: Printing the return value really helped. Isn't %f the placeholder for double? I had to change it to %lf, since %f was returning 0.0000 for every value.

Comment: @da_vinci_3864 `%f` is for `float`.

Comment: `printf("%f\n", Result);` ==> `printf("log(%f) = %f\n", x, Result);`

Comment: Forgot to paste stdio.h here.

Comment: I used %f for printing the double, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are missing an include

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Secondly, you are not using the correct format specifier. You are using doubles, so you should use *%lf*. If you compile with the `-Wformat` flag, your compiler will warn you about this by telling you something like this:

```
/cplayground/code.cpp:16:17: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%f", &x);
           ~~   ^~
           %lf
```

If you fix these 2 problems, your program should finally work as expected.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintLogarithm(double x) {
    if(x<=0) {
        printf("Positive numbers only please.\n");
        return;
    }

    double Result = log(x);
    printf("%lf\n", Result);
}

int main() {
    double x;
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    PrintLogarithm(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit : As commenters pointed out, printf() works fine with either *%lf* or *%f* as the format specifier.

Comment: I forgot to paste stdio.h here. And, changing to lf worked.

Comment: @da_vinci_3864 It's a bit strange with floats and doubles.... For **double** and `scanf` you need `%lf`.  For **float** and `scanf` you need `%f`.  But for `printf` you can use `%f` for both double and float

Comment: @openTankist `%lf` is not needed for `printf`

Comment: @da_vinci_3864 Check the [manual for scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), you can see that "`l` Indicates ...  the next pointer is a pointer to double (rather than float)."

Comment: @4386427 It's not needed but considered good practice. The printf vs scanf inconsistency was fixed in C99.